# jQuery Mobile embedded list inside listview

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create an ordered list inside of a jQuery Mobile ListView. The problem is that the listview has the `data-autodividers="true"` and this also gets applied to the embedded ordered list. I've tried to set the `data-role="none"` on the `ol` and each of the `li`'s, and even set the `data-autodividers="false"` on the `ol`, and it still renders the dividers on the embedded `ol`. Is there a way to prevent the autodividers from being created in the first place?

I've hacked this problem by just targeting the embedded dividers and just setting them as `display:none`, but I'd rather just have jQuery Mobile not add the dividers in the first place.

Here's a JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/straker/eM8tb/

This is a similar question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422871/jquery-mobile-listview-and-formatting-embedded-html-lists, but deals with the autodividers and not the styling of the list (which is also wrong but can be fixed with CSS as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also didn't find in JQM doc.

but you can use this script to remove inner list autodivider.

see DEMO here http://jsfiddle.net/eM8tb/3/

## JQUERY

```
$( "ol#inner_list li" ).each(function() {
    var c = $(this).text();
    if (c.length == 1)
        $(this).remove();
});
```

## HTML

```
<ol id='inner_list' data-role="none" data-autodividers="false">
```